# robot_upstart uninstall, Job not found, nothing to remove

Tags: ros, robot-upstart

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, All
I tried to remove the auto start launch file which locates at `~/catkin_ws/src/roscopter/nodes/upstart.launch`
After system boot up, "rostopic list" gives a list of topics, which shows the launch file was excecuted.

I used following command to uninstall it

```
rosrun robot_upstart uninstall roscopter/nodes/upstart.launch
```

It returns

```
/lib/systemd/systemd
Job not found, nothing to remove
```

I tried

```
rosrun robot_upstart install roscopter/nodes/upstart.launch
```

it works.

I am confused and have no idea of what's the next step, anyone has ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262151/robot_upstart-uninstall,-job-not-found,-nothing-to-remove/) by [wuxiong2](https://answers.ros.org/users/26524/wuxiong2/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2017-05-19

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same problem but it seems the job name is the first part of the apparent package path so for example
rosrun robot_upstart uninstall roscoptor
This worked for me.

---

Originally posted by [dust](https://answers.ros.org/users/32171/dust/) with karma: 36 on 2017-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2017-10-07**:
The package's [document for uninstall](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/robot_upstart/html/uninstall.html) confirms this. Format of `install` and `uninstall` being different is a bit confusing indeed.